# How to update Android UI elements from loop while it still looping?

Tags: android

I need to update Android buttons from loop, to make each button highlighted one by one
[image]

I was trying use AsyncTask without success, the same with Handler.
below the Handler example [part from the code, just to give you example]:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
final int value = i;
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(value);
                    currentButton.setPressed(true);

                }
            });
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Any Idea how to reach UI elements one by one?
Another example: in below example in standard loop:
 - get button by id
 - setPressed(true) to make the button highlight
 - execute the wanted function
 - setPressed(false), only when the previous step was done.
The problem: while the loop running the buttons doesn't updated, only when the loop finished, in this case the user will not understand what step executed:
the below code is the event of Starting all the loop:

```
View.OnClickListener OnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
return new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("text now set.. ");
        UpdateStep updateStep;
        for(int i=1; i<stepsArray.size();i++)
      {
         final int value = i;
         Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(i);
         currentButton.setHighlightColor(0x7f050003);
         currentButton.setPressed(true);

         for(int x=0;x<900000;x++); // will be replaced with the real function

         currentButton.setPressed(false);
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: You should begin by understanding *why* the UI doesn't update when your app is in a loop.  Next you should (as you first attempted) learn how to run code asynchronously, i.e., on a separate thread.

Comment: @Ed - That's not running on the UI thread. Notice the last line of the posted code?

Comment: @Ted:....... d'oh.  Ok, it's just running too fast then.

Answer (score 1):

You are sleeping for zero time. Try increasing the sleep delay in the loop to something where you would notice the delay. You may also need to invalidate the display to get it to refresh (although I think buttons do that automatically when their pressed state changes).

An alternative would be to use Handler's `postDelayed` or `postAtTime` method to post updates at 10 points in the future, each progressively further off into the future, and eliminate the sleep entirely from your loop.

Are you forgetting to un-press the previous button?

EDIT: You are launching 10 threads all at once and they execute in an unspecified order. Launch a single thread and put the loop inside the thread's run method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,each button will execute a lot of http request in my real code, the sleep or delay will not help, because I want to leave the button only when the http requests finish running, then to un-press the button and move to next one.[the attached code is not my real code, only example]

Comment: Got it. In the example that you appended to your original post, the problem, I think, is that you are doing all that expensive execution on the UI thread (in the OnClickListener). That should be moved to a worker thread, either with an AsyncTask or a Thread you create.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this code is not crashing. Getting a view with an ID between 1 and 10 looks bad to me ;). You should normally use integers from the `R.id` class.

Secondly you should definitely use `Handler`s instead of `Thread`. Look at the `postDelayed` method.

Comment: the buttons was created dynamically, I set the id of each button, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using `Thread` and `Handler` with each other!!!
i think this code will be more accurate:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(value);
                    currentButton.setPressed(true);

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50);
        }
```

Comment: That won't do. It will run all the runnables at about the same time 50 ms from when the loop runs. It would work if you did something like `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500*i)`.

Comment: as i know, it will not, it will be Delayed 50 from the last message the handler received, i'll try it if i have time, and tell you the result, but i already have a code telling me that, but not sure, because i didnt implement it